# Equivalence classes of orthogonal matrices

Tags: permutations, lie-groups, equivalence-relations, orthogonal-matrices

Consider $O(n)$, the Lie group of $n{\times}n$ orthogonal matrices. 
Let $\pi$ be a given permutation of $(1,2,\ldots,n)$;
the elements of the corresponding permutation matrix are
\begin{eqnarray}
P_{i,j}
  &\equiv&
  \left\{
    \begin{array}
    {ccl}
      1  & \quad &  j = \pi(i)\\
      0  & & \text{else} 
    \end{array}
  \right. 
\end{eqnarray}
with $i,j = 1,\ldots,n$.
The set of matrices
$\{I,P,P^2,\ldots,P^{k-1}\}$ with $k$ denoting the order 
of $\pi$, 
form a subgroup of $O(n)$, 
since $P^m \cdot (P^m)^T = I$ with 
unit matrix $I$ and
$0\,{\le}\,m\,{\le}\,{k-1}$.
Now let's introduce an equivalence relation
on the matrices $R, S \in O(n)$
\begin{eqnarray}
R \sim S \iff S = P^m \cdot R \cdot (P^m)^T
\quad\text{with}\quad
0\,{\le}\,m\,{\le}\,{k-1}
\end{eqnarray}
If I'm not mistaken, this equivalence relation partitions the
Lie group $O(n)$ into an infinite set $X$ of equivalence classes
with each class containing $k$ matrices.

What kind of object is $X$?
Can it be expressed as a quotient group?
Naïve as I am, I would expect $X$ to be a group, too.
But I'm stuck at defining a meaningful way to 'multiply' 
two elements of $X$. Any advice would be greatly appeciated.

Comment: This is a group action of your $k$-element subgroup, and your description of the equivalence relation is the partitioning of $O(n)$ into the orbits of this action. Note that the identity is an orbit all by itself, so the orbits are most definitely *not* subgroups.